# Can't make gnome-screenshot to copy selected area to clipboard on Fedora 32

Tags: screenshot, fedora, gnome

I want to be able to screenshot selected area and copy it to clipboard.
I try:

```
gnome-screenshot -a -c
```

It lets me select the area, but afterwards nothing is copied to clipboard.

I'm using Fedora 32

Comment: Reading the `gnome-screenshot` issues on Gitlab, it seems that the clipboard entry only exists until the end of the program... not very useful on its own.  Maybe it'll work better with a clipboard manager installed?  Alternatively, perhaps `Shift`-`Ctrl`-`PrtSc` will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem in "Gnome-Wayland".
I use this script to copy screenshots

```
gnome-screenshot -a -f /tmp/screenshot.png && xclip -in -selection clipboard -target image/png /tmp/screenshot.png
```